# Deploy multiple ssis packages in msdb without rdp

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have made updates to approx. 100 ssis packages which are stored in ( msdb ), which is the location I need to deploy them.

[image: Options]

I do not have access to rdp into the server and hence I cannot run multiple dtutil commands on the server thru a bat file. I am looking for a way to deploy all the packages in some easy manner, but looking at this image, my only option is one package at a time. Without having to change the current setup what option do I possibly have?

Comment: How do you know what packages need to be deployed? What does having RDP access have to do with running a batch script?

Comment: Asked a different way, could you provide a sample of what your `dtutil` command would look like as that might explain why it's not a viable option

Comment: Sample command : DTUTIL /FILE "PackageName".dtsx /COPY SQL;"MSDB Folder location" /DESTSERVER servername

Comment: I got the packages from a peer in a network share.

Comment: I understand that dtutil can be run remotely using powershell, by writing dtutil commands in a bat file. But the packages that need to be deployed should be in some folder in the destination server. I do not have access to the folders. You can see in the image I posted that I cannot import more than one package at a time. Which is the issue I am facing.

Comment: dtutil can be run locally as well though so `dtutil /file "path\to\package.dtsx"` When you are using the `Import Package...` as shown in your image, SSMS is using the same objects that a dtutil call would make. I'm not following how dtutil on the same location as SSMS doesn't work.

Comment: I was using an older version of DTUTIL and it was throwing this error - Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. I changed it to use the DTUTIL at \150\DTS\Binn\DTUTIL.exe & it uploaded all the packages.

Comment: @billinkc thanks for your help. It let me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding was incorrect with regard to usage of DTUTIL.

Also I was using an older version of DTUTIL and it was throwing this error - Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "`Error loading from XML`", which made me think I will have to run my scripts locally on the server.

[This post helped me](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f9a00c74-cb10-49e9-86da-223d1dd3e232/ssis-packages-deployment-error-the-package-failed-to-load-due-to-error-0xc0011008-error-loading?forum=sqlintegrationservices) .I changed it to use the latest version of DTUTIL. Mine was at `c:\...\150\DTS\Binn\DTUTIL.exe` & it uploaded all the packages.